# ¿Por qué no puedo sugerir ediciones en meta?

Tags: soporte, ediciones-sugeridas

Iba a editar una pregunta en *Meta* para corregir algunos errores gramaticales y ortográficos pero me he encontrado con este mensaje:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He estado buscando si había alguna pregunta que tratara este tema o alguna sección en la ayuda pero no encuentro nada.

Por si esa pregunta tenía algo distinto he probado editar otras preguntas en *Meta* y en todas me ocurre igual. No entiendo que significa *publicaciones de wiki sin etiqueta*, los post que he intentado editar no son wiki y además si lo fueran podría incluso editarlos directamente, no sugerir ediciones.

---

Prueba de edición

Comment: Recién pude editar sin problemas. Dado que los wiki de comunidad pueden ser editados por cualquiera y que aparentemente tienes los privilegios de editar publicaciones de otros, podría haber sido un "glitch". Vuelve a intentarlo y si se repite el problema, has un reporte seleccionando la opción de se require la intervención de un moderador para que revise tu caso.

Comment: Necesitamos chequearlo con usuarios con menos de 2k de reputacion.. a mi me paso lo mismo cuando me postule.. te acuerdas que tu modificaste el post @Rubén?

Comment: @gbianchi: Si recuerdo, pero aquella pregunta no era wiki de comunidad :)

Comment: es que casi ninguna es wiki de comunidad.. por lo menos no las preguntas.. capaz hay una mala traduccion ahi?? dejame chequearlo...

Comment: exactamente.. es un grave problema de la traduccion del error.. dejame ver bien como se editan los post en meta y hago una respueta...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Como primera medida hay un problema con la traduccion del error..

en ingles dice

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

que se traduciría (IMHO) como:

Las ediciones sugeridas en publicaciones sin la etiqueta wiki (N.T. en nuestro sitio [wiki-de-comunidad](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wiki-de-comunidad) ) no se permiten en los sitios de meta.

Con lo cual, podríamos empezar por esto. primero corregir el problema de la traducción. Después se requieren 2k de reputación para modificar una publicación en meta que no tenga este etiqueta.

Comment: Vale, entonces el problema es una mala traducción. Y entiendo que en Meta no se pueden sugerir ediciones y solo podré editar cuando tenga privilegios de edición ¿es así?

Comment: He encontrado un post en el meta de [StackExchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work#answer-76284) donde entre otras muchas cosas dice que en los sitios meta no se pueden sugerir ediciones.

Comment: 2019 - sugeriría esta traducción